# How can I use C-n and C-p as shortcut in ncdu

Tags: ncurses, du

I am using [ncdu - NCurses Disk Usage](https://github.com/rofl0r/ncdu) on a Linux server node through CLI.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS , Kernel: Linux 5.11.0-43-generic
- ncdu 1.14.1

I get used to Emacs keybindings and I never use arrow keys. After running `ncdu` I can only move arround using arrow keys in the list of files but I cannot use `C-n` and `C-p` as for down and up keys respectively.

Is it possible to bind use C-n and C-p as arrow keys in `ncdu`?

Comment: Yes sir I am using Ubuntu. Oh no! I haven't released the kernel is depreciated thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The 5.11 kernel stack was from Ubuntu 21.04 (it stopped getting patches when [21.04 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/); but updated LTS systems had it replaced with 5.13 from 21.10 which then moved to 5.15 from 22.04 LTS... ie. your system is using an *unpatched* sand *unsecured* kernel that isn't supported; as stated before the GA kernel stack was 5.4 & HWE is now 5.15 - those are what get security patches (plus some OEM options I mentioned but your kernel version doesn't show).

Comment: Should I try to update it to `5.15` without crashing the system? or to the latest version which seems like `v6.3.1`? and sorry that the commens out of the scope of the Q.

Comment: I would suggest staying with *supported* upgrades for your existing system; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS had two primary supported kernel paths; GA for servers wanting the most *stable* option or 5.4 for the life of the product, or HWE for those using newer hardware & wanting newer graphics stacks... plus some OEM options.. 6.3 isn't a supported kernel for *focal* or 20.04.  You've taken on applying security fixes yourself having moved away from a *supported* kernel stack.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack